# Am I able to get a list of delegators by validator (solana) using the JSON RPC API?

Tags: python, api, cryptocurrency, solana

So for instance in [solanabeach.io](https://solanabeach.io/validator/CAf8jfgqhia5VNrEF4A7Y9VLD3numMq9DVSceq7cPhNY), I am able to see for validator - "staked" a list of delegators containing addresses, activation epochs, amount staked, and share %.

Is it possible to get this via the JSON RPC API, or another method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly! You'll have to use the `get_program_accounts` endpoint, fetching all of the accounts belonging to the stake program, and filtering for where the delegation's vote account is equal to the validator that you want to search for.

Info about `get_program_accounts`: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts

Info about the stake structure: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e960634909a9617fb98d5d836c9c4c5e0d9d59cc/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L22

If you count up from the enum (4 bytes), then the `Meta` (8 bytes for `rent_exempt_reserve` + 64 bytes for `authorized` + 48 bytes for `lockup`) to get to `voter_pubkey`, that gives an offset of `124` bytes.

Here's a python script to do exactly that, requiring just the `solana-py` package:

```py
import asyncio

from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.types import MemcmpOpts

STAKE_PROGRAM_ID: PublicKey = PublicKey("Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111")


async def main():
    client = AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", Confirmed)
    print("Connecting...")
    await client.is_connected()

    memcmp_opts = [MemcmpOpts(offset=124, bytes="CAf8jfgqhia5VNrEF4A7Y9VLD3numMq9DVSceq7cPh
NY")] # put the pubkey of the validator vote address here
    response = await client.get_program_accounts(
        STAKE_PROGRAM_ID,
        encoding="base64",
        data_size=200,
        memcmp_opts=memcmp_opts
    )
    for stake in response['result']:
        print(stake)

    await client.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tried using the get_program_accounts but I wasn't wrapping the program id with PublicKey. Thank you!

Comment: I have another question. How can I get the staking rewards history for a stake account?

Comment: Certainly, you'd have to use https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getinflationreward for each epoch that you care about